# Cholesky Decomposition of a random exponential correlation matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, statistics, correlation, matrix-factorization

I have a set of exponential correlation matrices created using the following code.

```
x=runif(n)
R=matrix(0,n,n)  
for (j in 1:n)
{
  for(k in 1:n)
  {
    R[j,k]=exp(-(x[j]-x[k])^2);
  }
}
```

and now I want to get their Cholesky decomposition. But many of these are negative definite. How could I resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please use `set.seed(..)` for a replicable example. You can produce a positive semidefinite matrix by `crossprod(R)`. If det(R) > 0 then there is a even number of negative eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exponential correlation matrix used in spatial or temporal modeling, has a factor `alpha` that  controls the speed of decay:

```
exp(- alpha * (x[i] - x[j]) ^ 2))
```

You have fixed such factor at 1. But in practice, such factor is estimated from data.

Note that `alpha` is necessary to ensure numerical positive definiteness. This matrix is in principle positive definite, but numerically not if `alpha` is not large enough for a fast decay.

Given that `x <- runif(n, 0, 1)`, the distance between `x[i]` and `x[j]` is clustered in a short range `[0, 1]`.  This is not a big range to see a decay in correlation, and maybe you want to try `alpha = 10000`.

Alternatively if you want to stay with `alpha = 1`, you need to make distance more spread out.  Try `x <- runif(n, 0, 100)`. The decay is very fast, even with `alpha = 1`.

So we see a duality between distance and `alpha`. This is also the reason why such correlation matrix can be used stably in statistical modeling. When `alpha` is to be estimated, it can be made adaptive to distance, so that the correlation matrix is always positive definite.

---

Examples:

```
f <- function (xi, xj, alpha) exp(- alpha * (xi - xj) ^ 2)

n <- 100

# large alpha, small distance
x <- runif(n, 0, 1)
A <- outer(x, x, f, alpha = 10000)
R <- chol(A)

# small alpha, large distance
x <- runif(n, 0, 100)
A <- outer(x, x, f, alpha = 1)
R <- chol(A)
```

Answer (score 1):

try use this to construct the positive defitive matrix

```
A<-matrix(runif(n^2),n,n)
dim(A)
A<-A%*%t(A)
chol(A)
```